# Динамическое добавление элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: Было]

всем привет , помогите добавить элемент, при прокрутке меню должна появляться кнопка, а при топе

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var documentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  
  if (documentScrollTop > $('#header').height()) {
    $('#navbar').addClass('fixedattop');
    var shiftContent = $('#navbar').height();
    $('#content').css('margin-top', shiftContent + 'px');
  }
  else if ($('#navbar').hasClass('fixedattop')) {
    $('#navbar').removeClass('fixedattop');
    $('#content').css('margin-top', '0px');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#navbar").on("click","a", function (event) {
  //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
  event.preventDefault();
  //забираем идентификатор бока с атрибута href
  var id  = $(this).attr('href');
  //узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока 
  //на который ссылается якорь
   top = $(id).offset().top;
  //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
  $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
 });
});
```

```html
ul.nav__menu
                            li.nav__menu
                                a.nav__link(href="#link1") Почему мы?
                            li.nav__menu 
                                a.nav__link(href="#link2") Зачем клуб?
                            li.nav__menu
                                a.nav__link(href="#link3") Как работаем?
                            li.nav__menu
                                a.nav__link(href="#link4") Контакты
```

исчезать.

[image: должно быть]

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать так:

```js
  $(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() == 0)
    {
      $('.knopka').css('display','none');
    }
    else
    {
      $('.knopka').css('display','block'); 
    }
  })
```

```css
body
{
  height:1500px;
}
#header
{
  position: fixed;
}
.knopka
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="header">
<li class="knopka">Knopka</li>
</ul>
```